mypy checking pyi in venv despite excluding it
I have a PySide project set up using a pyproject.toml file, with venv+pip.
I have set up mypy in the pyproject.toml file as follows:
[tool.mypy]
disable_error_code = ["import-untyped"]
exclude = ["^.venv/", "^myproject/somefolder/"]

[[tool.mypy.overrides]]
module = "PySide6.*"
ignore_errors = true

However when running mypy . I get the following error:
venv\Lib\site-packages\PySide6\QtGui.pyi:1094: error: unexpected indent  [syntax]
Found 1 error in 1 file (errors prevented further checking)

This is caused by this issue in PySide: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-2665 and I'd like to ignore it.
What I've tried:

Check if somefolder is actually being ignored. It is, as when I remove the regex from the exclude, more errors show up.
Change the module to "PySide6". Still getting the same error.
Remove the [[tool.mypy.overrides]] and what's under it. Still getting the same error.
Using strings instead of regexes: exclude = ["venv","myproject/somefolder"]. Still the same.

The mypy documentation only mentions how to ignore individual files (link).
So how would I go about fixing this?

A syntax error cannot be ignored. Even in your dependencies. It's such a critical trouble that it was never allowed (and never considered necessary as far as I know). Why is that syntax error there? Can you do something to resolve it? mypy does not check that module for typing errors, it only tries to use type information provided by it and dies due to invalid syntax. You can either remove that pyi file (so that it isn't analyzed at all) or fix the mistake.

Ah that's terrible then. There is already an issue in the dep's bug tracker for it. Added a link in the OP.
Eventually I fixed it by running a sed to fix that specific line, since it seems that it's then not possible to make mypy act like the pyi file doesn't exist?

Yeah, your options are limited to removing that file or fixing it manually (with script, in Dockerfile, with vim - whichever way fits your workflow). If there's a ticket and you know how to fix it - go ahead and submit a PR. You already have a solution, please consider spending 15 minutes of your time and contributing it upstream. Maintainers may not have enough time now to fix it, but often warmly welcome PRs which are focused and easy to review and merge them promptly. You'll save yourself that sed later as well:)

yep, same issue here, how could this syntax error get into that dependency? mypy .\widget.py
...\lib\site-packages\PySide6\QtGui.pyi:1073: error: unexpected indent  [syntax]
Found 1 error in 1 file (errors prevented further checking)

@masterxilo in the meantime the syntax error I mentioned in the OP has been fixed (in versions  6.2.13, 6.7.1, 6.8.0 and up). If you have a version older than those, upgrade to one of those. If you have a newer version, open a ticket on the Qt bugtracker.
